# Patching an array in directus via api-call does not work

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, api, directus

I am trying to perform an API call to patch the name and translations of an element. 
`translations` is an array with the elements `name` and `alt_name` identified with a unique id. 
The code:

```py
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

for row in reader:
    data = '{"name": "' + row[1] + '", "alt_name": "' + row[2] + '", ' \
            '"translations": [' + \
                '{' + \
                    '"id": "661", "name": "' + row[1] + '", "alt_name": "' + row[2] + '"}, ' + \
                '{' + \
                    '"id": "662", "name": "' + row[3] + '", "alt_name": "' + row[4] + \
           '"}]}'

    base_url = 'https://URL/path?&access_token=TOKEN'
    resp = requests.patch(base_url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Everything except inside translations can be modified without problems. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You need the translations:[] only (remove the preceding name and alt_name).